# React useEffect in depth / use of useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to understand the `useEffect` hook in-depth.

I would like to know when to use which method and why?

1. useEffect with no second paraments

```
useEffect(()=>{})
```

2. useEffect with second paraments as `[]`

```
useEffect(()=>{},[])
```

3. useEffect with some arguments passed in the second parameter

```
useEffect(()=>{},[arg])
```

Comment: 1. Is being called on mount and every dependency update (any state / props change). 2. Only called on mount because you specified empty list of dependencies. 3. Called on mount and on change of any of the listed dependencies

Comment: Dan Abramov has written an excellent blog post about useEffect: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/. You should read it ;-)

Answer (score 53):

```
useEffect(callback);

// Example
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("executed after render phase");

  return () => {
    console.log("cleanup function after render");
  };
});
```

- Runs **on every** component render.
- Typically used for debugging, analogous to function's body execution on every
  render:

```
const Component = () => {
  callback()
  return <></>;
};
```

> *Note*: There is still a difference, in execution time (see the next note). [Check this sandbox logs](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-execute-phase-rk1re).

- The [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) runs after each render.

---

```
useEffect(callback,[]);

// Example
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const users = await fetch();
    setUsers(users);
  };

  fetchUsers();
  console.log("called on component's mount");

  return () => {
    console.log("called on component's unmount");
  };
}, []);
```

- Usually used for initializing components state by data fetching etc.
- Runs **once** on a component mount.
- The [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) will run on component's **unmount**.

**Gotchas:**

- The callback executed **after** the [render phase](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).

> Remember, there is a **first render** and **then** a mount.

- Stale data due to [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

> Roughly saying, most of bugs regarding `useEffect` is **not knowing** how closures works and not paying attention to **linting warnings**.

> Make sure the array **includes all values from the component scope**  that change over time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, **your code will reference stale values from previous renders** - [note in React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect).

---

```
useEffect(callback,[arg]);

// Example
useEffect(() => {
  console.log({ users });

  return () => {
    console.log("user value is changing");
  };
}, [users]);
```

- Runs **on change** of `arg` value.
- Usually used to run events on props/state change.
- Multiple dependencies can be provided: `[arg1,arg2,arg3...]`
- The cleanup function runs on `arg` value change.

Gotchas:

- *"On Change"* refers to **[shallow comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)** with the previous value of `arg`.

> i.e compares the value of `arg` from the previous render and the current one, `prevArg === arg ? doNothing() : callback()`.

- Because in Javascript `{} === {} || [] === []` is a **falsy** statement, if `arg` (`users` in our example) is an object, the callback will run on every render.
- Runs on mount too, since the first comparison always falsy

---

### Additional Good to Know Points

- `useEffect` callbacks [fired after browser's re-paint](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects).
- `useEffect` callbacks **executed in declaration order** ([like all hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)), check the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-order-fjfus).
- Every `useEffect` should have a [SINGLE responsibility](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns).
- If you using a value from `useRef`, in the cleanup function, copy the value to callback's scope beforehand.

```
const timeoutIdRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutId = timeoutIdRef.current;
  return () => {
  /*
    Using timeoutIdRef.current directly here is not safe
    since you can't guarantee the ref to exists in this point
    (especially when the component unmounts)
  */
    // Should get a lint warning here
    clearTimeout(timeoutIdRef.current); // BAD

    // Closure on timeoutId value
    clearTimeout(timeoutId); // GOOD
  };
}, [arg]);
```

- [Is it safe to use `ref.current` as `useEffect`'s dependency when ref points to a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476155/is-it-safe-to-use-ref-current-as-useeffects-dependency-when-ref-points-to-a-dom/60476525#60476525)
- Sometimes you need to run `useEffect` **ONCE**, on mount or on first render, [those are the common patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492626/stop-useeffect-from-running-on-mount/59492738#59492738).

```
const isMounted = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isMounted.current) {
    // first mount
  } else {
    isMounted.current = true;
  }
}, [arg]);
```

---

Keep reading:

- My [additional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65225493/7882470) explaining the `return` statement of `useEffect` callback
- [A Complete Guide to `useEffect` by Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)
- [`useEffect` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)
- [Using the effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) - React docs

Comment: Note that missing dependencies can lead to [stale closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). The following code: `const [s, setS] = useState(0); useEffect(() => setInterval(() => console.log(s), 1), []);` will only ever log 0 because the callback closes over s and even though the function is re created on every render it will only be called on mount and at time s was 0. See questions pop up many times having to do with this error and asynchronous setting of state is blamed but with functional components it's root cause is stale closures.

Comment: `run on every render` i would re-word that as `runs after each render` and the cleanup function `runs before each unmount, either the final unmount or before the next render attempt`

Comment: "runs before each unmount, either the final unmount or before the next render attempt" its sound like there is aways an "unmount attempt", but there isn't such.

Comment: There are one of those answers which you want to put inside a frame and read every week

Answer (score 2):

If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

1.useEffect with no second paraments : This is used when we want something to happen either when the component just mounted, or if it has been updated.  Conceptually, we want it to happen after every render.

2.useEffect with second paraments as [] : This is used when we want something to happen at the time of mounting of the component, if only executes once at the time of mounting.It is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount.

3.useEffect with some arguments passed in the second parameter:This is used when we want something to happen at the time when the pramter passed eg. args have changed in your case.

For more info. check here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html