# React: Re-render behavior

Tags: reactjs

I'm somewhat new to react, and I'm trying to learn when every time a component will re-render. Usually I'm good at figuring this stuff out on my own, but I can't seem to find the logic in these

**Exhibit A**

```
const Science = () => {
    console.log('Rendering')

    useEffect(() => console.log('Effect ran'))

    console.log('Returning')

    return <div></div>
}
```

This outputs

```
Rendering
Returning
Rendering
Returning
Effect ran
```

I don't understand why it re-renders, and why the useEffect code comes after both renders and returns.

**Exhibit B**

```
const Science = () => {
    console.log('Rendering')

    useEffect(() => console.log('First effect ran'))
    useEffect(() => console.log('Second effect ran'))

    console.log('Returning')

    return <div></div>
}
```

This outputs

```
Rendering
Returning
Rendering
Returning
First effect ran
Second effect ran
```

My guess to why it re-renders in Exhibit A was that useEffect causes a re-render, but seen here, only one useEffect will cause a re-render. Unsure of this behavior.

**Exhibit C**

```
const Science = () => {
    console.log('Rendering')

    let numRenders = useRef(0)
    console.log(++numRenders.current)

    console.log('Returning')

    return <div></div>
}
```

This one really confuses me, as it outputs

```
Rendering
1
Returning
Rendering
1
Returning
```

I don't understand why on the second render, it doesn't increment. I know that it does permanently increment the value, and not just for the logging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, your jsx is rendered. Then lifecycle hooks executed and the component is rerendered. then each time that any state changes the component is rendered or props are changed.

Your useEffect code doesn't have any dependencies but you did not mention it. This way is correct in this case

```
useEffect(() => console.log("useEffect was ran") , [])
```

Comment: It is not "the correct way", it is just the API, the "correct way" depends on the situation

Comment: I meant in this case

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` **callback** executed asynchronously **after** the [render phase](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/), that's exactly **A** and **B**.

As for **Exhibit C**, it outputs:

```
Rendering 
1
Returning
```

And **not rendered twice**, it renders twice because of other reasons (like a render of a parent which you not showing us). Anyways, `useRef` **doesn't trigger** render so [due to closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) updating the reference is pointless (it will always show the first value rendered).

In other words, as it's **function component**, render **triggers** the function and the updated value will be valuated.

See codesandbox attached.

[image: Edit priceless-silence-r3x4r]

Comment: That could be true, there is a parent component (App.tsx), so maybe it is causing the re-render. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to answer all your questions, see related question it may help either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947