# API is getting called over and over again when I am using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using `React Hooks` to get data from an existing API. Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const People = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/people";

  async function fetchData() {
    console.log("calling api .. ");
    const res = await fetch(url);
    res.json().then((res) => setPeople(res));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {people &&
          people.map((person) => <li key={person.id}>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const Dashboard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <People />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

The problem that I am having is this API is getting called over and over again. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Please read docs about useEffect hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, using `useEffect(callback)` will **execute** the callback on **every render**.

Try using `useEffect` with [an empty dependencies array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect).

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up **only once**, you can pass an empty array (`[]`) as a second argument. **This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run**.

- Check my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59841947/7882470) on `useEffect` use cases.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

As for the rest of the component, it should look like so (opinioned):

```
// Should be on the outer scope as the URL is decoupled from the component's logic
const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/people";

export const People = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
  // This way fetchData won't re-assigned on every render
    async function fetchData() {
      console.log("calling api .. ");
      const res = await fetch(URL);

      // Consitstance, don't mix `then` and `await` syntax
      const people = await res.json();
      setPeople(people);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {people &&
          people.map((person) => <li key={person.id}>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but what does it do  ? Can you please elaborate a bit more ? thanks a ton..

Comment: Loop was existing because `useEffect` is called every time a state in component changes and in hook you referred to `fetchData()` which changes the state. With empty dependency array it runs only once just like `componentDidMount`.

Comment: @Gagan ```useEffect``` will trigger when values of variables in second arg (as array) have change, So when there is an empty array, It means ```componentDidMount```.

Comment: Thanks, Guys.. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Removing StrictMode in Index.js has resolved for me. you can refer below link.

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-why-is-console-log-printed-twice

Comment: your answer does not relate to the question.