# Should I use useEffect() for dom manipulation or just do it directly?

Tags: reactjs

In the [React docs I see this piece of code](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  //THE SUBJECT OF MY QUESTION:
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So, my question is why not change the document.title or any other DOM without using useEffect, like this:

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  //THE SUBJECT OF MY QUESTION:
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know that when sending requests for example, it is asynchronous and we need to do it in  useEffect. But DOM manipulation isn't asynchronous and it takes relatively 0 time, why do we then still have to use useEffect hook?

Comment: useEffect without second params ([]) render every time state change so in my oponion it is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You better keep DOM manipulations and other side effects inside `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]); // set your dependencies
```

Reason is: This approach is compliant with [React Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) and upcoming [Concurrent Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html).

What Concurrent mode [is](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects):

> [...] React may invoke **render** phase lifecycles **more than once** before committing, or it may invoke them without committing at all (because of an error or a higher priority interruption).

In your case, the `document.title` assignment  might be repeated multiple times or React might even decide to abort the whole commit. In general, this can lead to inconsistencies:

> Because the above methods might be called more than once, it’s important that they do **not** contain **side-effects**. Ignoring this rule can lead to a variety of problems, including memory leaks and invalid application state. ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects))

Comment: Thanks for pointing out concurrent mode bit, it cleared lot of my doubts.

Answer (score 5):

Its **almost** the same, see my related answer, [useEffect in-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59841947/7882470).

The difference is a notable "gotcha", `useEffect` callback executed [**after** the render phase](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("executed after render phase");
  });

  console.log("executed at render phase");

  return <></>;
};
```

Will result:

```
executed at render phase
executed after render phase
```

[image: Edit useEffect execute phase]

Answer (score 2):

It's important to know how `useEffect` works.

Here's some clarity.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // this runs when the component mounts

  return () => {
    // This runs when the component unmounts (not useful for you right now)
  }
}, []); // You were missing the second argument (dependencies array)
```

Regarding the `dependencies` array. Putting values in there will cause your effect to run again when that value changes, which is very useful for your need.

What you should do is the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]);
```

This will update `document.title` whenever `count` changes.

I generally recommend making use of `useEffect` for these kinds of situations over not using it simple because it will take all the life-cycle processes into account.

*TLDR: It should perform better.*

Comment: He asked about the example in docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: I see that, I still stand by my answer. Not making use of `useEffect` means that the `document.title` will get reset everytime anything else changes. I believe the dependency array is a very important part of the `useEffect` hook that shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: It is not ignored... Its a beginner guide which explains it when you progress reading, your answer is at the end of the page... https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects