# The old "useEffect has a missing dependency" when calling an outside function

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Yes, I know this question have been asked zillion times, **but** none of the answers are fit to my code.

My `useEffect()` calls an outside function (`showIncrement()`) that logs my `increment` state value. The problem is `showIncrement()` is also used by a button, so I can't move it inside the `useEffect()` scope.

I know a few solutions to this:

- re-create the function inside `useEffect()`, but then I have two identical functions
- use the React `useCallback()` function, React documentation call it *the last resort*, and other answer in another question also don't recommend using it, so I'm not really sure

The question is, **what is the best way to solve this problem? Is it safe to use `useCallback()`?**

Here's my code:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [increment, setIncrement] = React.useState(2);
    const showIncrement = React.useCallback(() => console.log(increment), [
        increment,
    ]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        showIncrement();
    }, [showIncrement]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button type="button" onClick={showIncrement}>
                Show Increment
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: What is the meaning of this `useEffect`? Are you trying to call `showIncrement` on every render or just on mount?

Comment: your button using the same function would not prevent hoisting it outside the component. That is only not an option when `showIncrement` uses anything from the component scope.

Comment: @DennisVash The code above is just a simplified version of my code. It doesn't have any meaning in real projects. I just want to know how `useEffect` works.

Comment: You asking generic question, it depends on what is the use case, `useCallback` depends on the use case

Comment: Then read [this](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: Now because `useEffect` runs on every render, this `useEffect` pretty useless, you can just call `showIncrement()` in function body instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `showIncrement` doesn't need access to update the state variables, the easiest way to fix this is to move it outside the component, so it won't be recreated on every render and have a stable reference:

```
const showIncrement = (increment) => console.log(increment);

const App = () => {
    const [increment, setIncrement] = React.useState(2);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        showIncrement(increment);
    }, [increment]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button type="button" onClick={() => showIncrement(increment)}>
                Show Increment
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Another way is to use the `useCallback` hook:

```
const App = () => {
  const [increment, setIncrement] = React.useState(2);
  const showIncrement = React.useCallback(() => console.log(increment), [
    increment
  ]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    showIncrement();
  }, [showIncrement]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={showIncrement}>
        Show Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is it safe to use `useCallback()`? My other code need to access the `setIncrement()`.
Edit: Thanks for the quick answer, your first solution solves my question's answer (IDK why someone downvoted it).

Comment: It is perfectly safe to use it, but sometimes there are better options.

Comment: `showIncrement` will run on every `increment` change, while in question you see it as only on mount.

Comment: @DennisVash ohh, right. I forgot to edit that part.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this situation, you want to:

- Re-use `showIncrement` logic.
- Run `showIncrement` on component's mount.
- Not violate linter warnings.

The problem here is that `showIncrement` depends on state value `increment`, so either way, your `useEffect` has to include `increment` in dep array.

Usually, you go for `useCallback` when its dep array (`[increment]` in this case) **not frequently changes**.

So depending on your use case, since `showIncrement` triggered only `onClick` it seems like a good choice.

```
const App = () => {
  const [increment] = React.useState(2);
  const isMounted = useRef(false);

  const showIncrement = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(increment);
  }, [increment]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMounted.current) {
      showIncrement();
    }
  }, [showIncrement]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={showIncrement}>
        Show Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```