# useEffect triggered by a context change AFTER component mounts

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to run a function on a `context` using `useEffect`, but after the component mounts. Otherwise the function runs as the context is first loaded in, and gives a bad result.  I'd love to nest a `useEffect` inside another `useEffect` that runs after load, but I cant.  How do I trigger the `useEffect` to wait until componentDidLoad to run? Do I need to revert my functional component to a class function?

Here is the effect im running

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let count = Object.keys(context).filter((x) => context[x] !== "").length;
    numChange = count;
  }, [context]); <=== run AFTER the original update of the context
```

To clarify. The context is an object, and I count how many of the objects properties have values. As the context is initially counted (let's say 5 out of the 10 properties already had values), the "number === 5". But what I want to do is count the changes after the initial amount of properties with values in the context when the component mounts. So if n = 5, I want to count any property that gets a value after n.

Comment: clarified in a paragraph below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your `useEffect` has a dependency and you want to act it like a `componentDidMount`, adding a ref check is enough:

```
const isMounted = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isMounted.current) {
    let numChange = Object.keys(context).filter((x) => context[x] !== "")
      .length;
    setState(numChange);
    isMounted.current = true;
  }
}, [context]);
```

See [use cases of `useEffect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947) for more context and examples.

Comment: This works, but I think because one of my values is coming in from an API call, the count is 1 (instead of 5). Maybe I need an await or something.