# React component life cycle: what is difference between render and return and happens after the return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

This is a generalized question about concepts in react component life cycles.
Below is some example code. Please treat the code as just a vague reference.

```
const Modal = ({
  className,
  variant,
  width,
  withCloseIcon,
  isOpen: propsIsOpen,
  onClose: tellParentToClose,
  renderLink,
  renderContent,
}) => {
  
  const [stateIsOpen, setStateOpen] = useState(false);
  const isControlled = typeof propsIsOpen === 'boolean';
  const isOpen = isControlled ? propsIsOpen : stateIsOpen;
  
  const $modalRef = useRef();
  const $clickableOverlayRef = useRef();

  const closeModal = useCallback(() => {
    if (!isControlled) {
      setStateOpen(false);
    } else {
      tellParentToClose();
    }
  }, [isControlled, tellParentToClose]);


  useEffect(() => {

    console.log('check useEffect')

    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // why bother? since always return "visible"

    return () => {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
    };
  }, [isOpen]);

  return (
    <Fragment>

      {isOpen &&
        ReactDOM.createPortal(
          <ScrollOverlay>
            <ClickableOverlay variant={variant} ref={$clickableOverlayRef}>
              <StyledModal
                className={className}
                ref={$modalRef}
              >
                {withCloseIcon && <CloseIcon type="close" variant={variant} onClick={closeModal} />}
                {renderContent({ close: closeModal })}
              </StyledModal>
            </ClickableOverlay>
          </ScrollOverlay>,
          $root,
        )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

I noticed that in functional components, the function I pass into the hook useEffect() is executed after the return() is executed. (`console.log('check useEffect')` defined in useEffect() is only executed after some other console log is executed within the `renderContent` method inside the `return()` ).

1. I know by definition, `useEffect()` is invoked after the component finishes rendering. So what does it mean to have `render` finished?
2. what is the relationship between a component "renders" and a component "returns" (React functional component)
3. within the `useEffect()`, we are always returning `document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';`, so why even bother running `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';` before the return?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's define some keywords.

What's paint ?

> Paint: the user agent has performed a "paint" (or "render") when it
> has converted the render tree to pixels on the screen. Formally, we
> consider the user agent to have "rendered" a document when it has
> performed the update the rendering steps of the event loop.

[Paint reference](https://w3c.github.io/paint-timing/#sec-terminology)

What's `render` and how it works?

Basically, the render process is browser painting with little more steps. React needs to define what to (re)render and what not. This process is also called Reconciliation.

[More on reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#motivation)

Question 1

`useEffect` waits for the browser to finish painting so that your rendering process is not blocked by your `useEffect` execution. If you don't want to wait for paint to finish you can use `useEffectLayout`

Question 2

Check this wonderful article from Dan Abramov (One of the core members of React)

[Class vs Functional Components](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/)

Question 3 and first part of Q1

I can't explain better than this person did. So check this one out as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65225493/7942117