# Why setInterval() is executed twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why "hi" is being logged in the console each second twice?

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => console.log("hi"), 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Because that's what [setInterval does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)?

Comment: try `setTimeout` instead

Comment: checked it, on my side, "hi" is being logged once every second. https://jsfiddle.net/4uchfrvm/3/

Comment: I'm guessing that `useEffect` is being called twice which causes setInterval to be called twice.

Comment: Could be [a side effect of React's Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)?

Comment: setInterval calls console.log("hi") two times, then in a second two more times and so on. Each second we have +2 console.logs.

Answer (score 0):

because that's what `setInterval` is all about.

From MDN:

> The setInterval() method, offered on the Window and Worker interfaces, repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

So you don't want to use `setInterval` because it will repeatedly execute your function, instead use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Comment: setInterval calls console.log("hi") two times, then in a second two more times and so on. Each second we have +2 console.logs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @AngryJohn wrote, you should also clear the interval when the component unmounts, by using [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) like so:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => console.log("hi"), 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer)  // This "return" function executes when a component unmounts
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65225094/when-does-the-useeffects-callbacks-return-statement-execute) SO question for more information.

Comment: i guess `interval` and `timer` should be the same variable.