# Getting null values from state before fetching actual data from API call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I understand that there is a initial state of the data i.e 'null' before fetching the data from API call. But when API is called the data should update , instead log shows me 2 null values before logging actual data.

```
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    const { user } = isAuthenticated();

    useEffect(() => {
        getUser(user.userId)
            .then()
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setData(result);
                },
                (error) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setError(error);
                }
            )
    }, [])

    console.log(data)
```

[image]

Why am I getting these null values before actual data?
How to avoid these null values?
Those initial null values are causing errors if I try to show that value on page.

Comment: You're probably running in Strict Mode, which will render your element twice with empty data. This won't happen in production, only in dev.

Comment: don't log there, Log in your result callback after you get data.

Comment: No I am not running in strict mode @codemonkey

Comment: Also what's with the empty `then()`? Seem redundant.

Comment: @SwetaDash why you dont debug your code?

Comment: Well I m fairly new to this framework. I was getting "Promise<pending>" instead of JSON data if I remove the empty then(). So I kept it there. @codemonkey

Comment: Go through this you will be master in your programming https://medium.com/@auchenberg/live-edit-and-debug-your-react-apps-directly-from-vs-code-without-leaving-the-editor-3da489ed905f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [`StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) (calling `render` function twice) you get two logs of `null` in the console on the **first** render.

Also, you have two state changes that aren't batched (`setIsLoaded`, `setData`), React doesn't batch state changes in promises.

Therefore you have log (`null`) on the first render, another one (`null`) on `setIsLoaded`, and finally the data from `setData`.

And because you use `useEffect`, the callback will be called [**after** the first render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947).

Comment: Not using StrictMode!

Comment: Yes, you have another state change `setIsLoaded` on complete, state change in promises **not** batched.

Comment: Yes you were right , just by changing the order of setData() and setIsLoaded()  removed one null value. Still one null exists though.

Comment: Ofc it exists, you have an initial value null, and as mentioned in the answer ***useEffect callback runs after the first render****

Comment: I tried not using useEffect() and just called the function, it logged data indefinitely, still got the first one null, which is obvious because that' the initial value. Any idea on how should I tweak the code to handle that initial null value?

Comment: You shouldnt tweak nothing, thats how it works, read about conditional rendering, and read about ajax calls in React docs