# converting componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate into hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

New to react hook world, trying to learn by coding,  i'm not sure about this `componentDidUpdate` to where put it inside `useEffect` any suggestions ?
this is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (!this.props.realGraph) {
    this.loadGraph();
  }
  
  this.refs.graphDiv.addEventListener("click", this.onClickGraphDiv, true);
}

discardGraph() {
  this.props.clearGraphData();
  this.loadGraph();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this._zoomConfig();
}

_zoomConfig = () => {
  const z = d3Select(`#graph-id-graph-wrapper`)
  .call(d3Zoom())
  .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
  .on("mousedown.zoom", null)
};
```

`realGrpah` comes from `mapStateToProps`

this is what i have done converting it to hooks,

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!props.realGraph) {
    loadGraph();
  }
  
  refs.graphDiv.addEventListener("click", onClickGraphDiv, true);
  _zoomConfig();
}, []);


discardGraph() {
  props.dispatch(clearGraphData())
  loadGraph();
}

_zoomConfig = () => {
  const z = d3Select(`#graph-id-graph-wrapper`)
  .call(d3Zoom())
  .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
  .on("mousedown.zoom", null)
};
```

Comment: See [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) [A great video about useEffect - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1ZRyw7OtZs) and [inDepth stackOverflow answer on using useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947)

Comment: [This](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/react+functional+component+unmount) can help you understand your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a separate effect that fires on every re-render:

```js
// Approximately component did mount
useEffect(() => {
  if (!props.realGraph) {
    loadGraph();
  }  
  refs.graphDiv.addEventListener("click", onClickGraphDiv, true);
}, []);

// Approximately component did update
useEffect(() => {
  _zoomConfig();
})
```

Now if you don't want it to fire on the *first* render, you can create a ref to a boolean that you use to ignore the initial mounting, which I believe would be more analogous to `componentDidUpdate`:

```js
// Approximately component did mount
useEffect(() => {
  if (!props.realGraph) {
    loadGraph();
  }  
  refs.graphDiv.addEventListener("click", onClickGraphDiv, true);
  _zoomConfig();
}, []);

// Approximately component did update
const isMounted = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
  if (!isMounted.current) {
    isMounted.current = true;
  } else {
    _zoomConfig();
  }
})
```

Comment: so this will do it also : useEffect(() => {
  if (!props.realGraph) {
    loadGraph();
  }
  
  refs.graphDiv.addEventListener("click", onClickGraphDiv, true);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  _zoomConfig();
}) ?

Comment: Yes, you can have two effects in the same component

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it clearer that you can have multiple effects

Comment: what is the difference between my version which is one useEffect and yours where is two ? i mean functionality

Comment: Your version has an empty dependency array, which is the second argument you're passing to the `useEffect` function. Since the dependency array is empty, it will only run on component mount and never again. When there's _no_ dependency array, it will run on every render. When there are variables in the dependency array, it'll run every time one of those variables changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not a super expert in react, but following solution might be useful for your scenario -

> For `DidMount`, the use case is very straightforward -

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your code
}, []); // passing an empty dependency array will fire it only for the first time when component renders
```

> For achieving `DidUpdate`, You can pass a prop from your parent component to your current component & fire an effect on updation of that prop as follows -

for example, you've used this component in parent component as -

```
const [updateZoom, setUpdateZoom] = useState(0);    // using this to update child component

// handleZoom on some event
const handleZoom = () => {
    setUpdateZoom(uz => uz + 1);
}

return (
    <GraphComponent realGraph={realGraph} clearGraphData={clearGraphData} updateZoom={updateZoom} />
);
```

And use `updateZoom` in your current/ child component as follows -

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('updateZoom did update');
    this._zoomConfig();
}, [updateZoom]);
```