# Why does React render component for the second time after setting the state to the same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React component and I set the same value each time that I click on the button:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

let data = { title: 'ABC' };

export default function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState();

  console.log('Rendered');

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setFoo(data)}>Set Data</button>
      <h1>Data: {JSON.stringify(foo)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But renders are a little bit strange because at the second button click React renders the component but I set the same value.
Why React re-render the component although I set the same value?

[image: Demo Image]

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zdq6qy)

Comment: Anytime setState is called, a re-render is actioned.

Comment: Because you've created a new string object.

Comment: It may be "rerendered" by react, but the DOM will likely not change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is about why the component renders although the new state equals the previous state (shallow comparison)

```
// On second button click
const prevState = data

// State trigger
setFoo(data)

// Same state, it doesn't triggers a render
data === prevState
```

**So, the component didn't trigger render due to state change.**

But **it happened due to another reason**, as mentioned in docs "between the lines" under Hooks API **Bailing out of a state update** section:

> Although in some cases React may still need to call your component before skipping the children, it shouldn’t affect your code ([react.dev](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState)).

> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out ([legacy.reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html?fbclid=IwAR2xkHsXuFdVHp93tBsCS1F32CgzA5yLKuUxr_lz1y7QU5Tc20S3ONYZ1l0#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)).

Unlike in class component, for function components, after setting the **same state** like in our case, **sometimes**, React will need another render to validate its equality. **Its unfortunate edge case**.

But it should not consider you as "performance issue" since it does not effect the `React.Node` tree, it won't continue in the [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) process if the state didn't change. It even won't make unnecessary hooks calls.

### Another Simplified Example

Same goes here, there is another render for bail out, another log of "A".

Although there is a "bail out" render, notice that the `useEffect` does not run.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("B");
  });

  console.log("A");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{state}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setState(42)}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit React state trigger]

If you wondering on logs order ("Why 'A' logged before 'B'?"), try deep diving another question: [React `useEffect` in depth / use of `useEffect`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947)

Comment: Thanks for the Golden tips! ❤️

Answer (score 1):

In functional component, a component isn't re-rendered if it's the same value, i.e. a value that passes === comparison:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});
...
setState(state => state); // no re-render
```

Otherwise a component is re-rendered:

```
setState(state => ({...state})); // re-render
```

As commented already, it may be "rerendered" by react, but the DOM will likely not change.

Checkout https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17474