# when I have multiple use effects which useeffect cleanup function will be called

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, mern

I am very new to react and I am experimenting with react hooks

lets say I have a component that has multiple useeffect hooks. both the useeffect hooks have a cleanup function. My questions are

1. in what order those cleanup function be called
2. will both the functions be called every time a component unmounts
3. any real life example of having multiple cleanup functions

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are called in declaration order [as mentioned in Rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

So goes for clean-up functions, therefore both cleanup functions will be called on component's unmount.

Refer to ["uses of `useEffect`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947) for detailed explanation on functionalitty differences of cleanup callbacks.

Moreover, test your assumptions by running simple logs example:

```
const Component = ({ isMounted }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mount 1");

    return () => {
      console.log("Mount 1 out");
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mount 2");

    return () => {
      console.log("Mount 2 out");
    };
  }, [isMounted]);

  return <>Test</>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [isMounted, toggle] = useReducer((p) => !p, true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("1");

    return () => {
      console.log("1 out");
    };
  }, [isMounted]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("2");

    return () => {
      console.log("2 out");
    };
  }, [isMounted]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggle}>{isMounted ? "unmount" : "mount"}</button>
      <div>{isMounted && <Component {...{ isMounted }} />}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit fancy-firefly-qw543]

Answer (score 0):

***in what order those cleanup function be called*** (run the function at the end)

[image]

***will both the functions be called every time a component unmounts***

Yes, as you can see in this example, all use effects with an return statement (as "unmount") are executed every time the component unmounts.

***any real life example of having multiple cleanup functions***

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Welcome = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect 1")
        return () => {
            console.log("useEffect1 cleanup")
        }
    }, [])


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect 2")
        return () => {
            console.log("useEffect2 cleanup")
        }
    }, [])


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect 3")
        return () => {
            console.log("useEffect3 cleanup")
        }
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>Welcome !</div>
    )
}


export default function UnStack() {
    const [show, setShow]=useState(true)



    return (
        <div>
            {show && <Welcome />}
            <button type='button' onClick={()=>setShow((prev) => !prev)}>unmount sidebar</button>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: By real life example I mean on a real project(not sandbox environment) where this is used

Comment: Just copy this code and use as your App.js. also please upvote my answer if it is helpful for you