# How to fetch data after a specific Interval with useState, useEffect and useCallback in React with proper dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch Cameras from after a specific interval.
Once I fetch all cameras, I set camera in local state but if I try to `console.log` it I get nothing

```
const [allCameras, setAllCameras] = useState()

const fetchAllCameras = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getAllCameras();
      if(res.data.status_code === 0 && res.data.data){
        setAllCameras(res.data.data)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }, [])

  const _fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    fetchAllCameras()

    if(allCameras){
      // Nothing gets logged
      console.log("allCameras", allCameras)
    }

  // If I add allCameras as a dependency it triggers an infinite loop
  }, [fetchAllCameras])

  useEffect(() => {
    _fetchData();
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      _fetchData();
    }, FETCH_INTERVAL * 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
  }, [_fetchData]);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the goal is ? Your usage of useCallback & useEffect seems a bit redundant, at first glance it can be simplified a lot. 

Which is why more context on why you are trying to use the hooks will help to give an accurate answer :)

Comment: @IanLoubser I want to fetch all Cameras set it in local state and map through all the cameras

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply few fixes to your code:

- Each `useEffect` should have a single responsibility.
- `useCallback` is debatable unnecessary here (what you trying to memoize? You measured performance issues?)
- There is a closure on `allCameras` value, move it to separate `useEffect`.

```
const [allCameras, setAllCameras] = useState();

const fetchData = () => {
  const fetchAllCameras = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getAllCameras();
      if (res.data.status_code === 0 && res.data.data) {
        setAllCameras(res.data.data);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
  fetchAllCameras();
};

// On Mount
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);

// Interval
useEffect(() => {
  const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, FETCH_INTERVAL * 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
}, []);

// Check state
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(allCameras);
}, [allCameras]);
```

Read more at [`useEffect` use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947).

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful