# React , why is this useEffect being triggered on load?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following piece of code

```
const IssuesItems: React.FC<IProps> = function ({ issuesProp }) {
  const [issues] = useState<any>([...issuesProp]);
  const [paginatedIssues, setPaginatedIssues] = useState<any>([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<any>(1);
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState<any>(13);
  const [numberOfPages, setNumberOfPages] = useState<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set the number of pages
    const numberOfPages = Math.ceil(issues.length / itemsPerPage);
    console.log(numberOfPages);
    setNumberOfPages(numberOfPages);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(numberOfPages);
    const newArr = splitArray(issues, numberOfPages);
    console.log('new arr');
    console.log(newArr);
  }, [numberOfPages]);
```

Problem is that, the second useEffect, is triggered on load, when numberOfPages is null, shouldn't it be triggered only after setNumberOfPages is triggered for the first time?

I can fix it doing this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (numberOfPages != null) {
      const newArr = splitArray(issues, numberOfPages);
      console.log('new arr');
      console.log(newArr);
    }
  }, [numberOfPages]);
```

But should it only be fired after the numberOfPages state is modified by a setNumberOfPages call?

Comment: adding a reference in second array means, run the effect after componentDidMount and any changes on the second item ! I think the best solution is adding a `if` to check `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, **`useEffect` always runs after the first render**.

The dependency array in `useEffect` lets you specify the conditions to trigger it. If you provide `useEffect` an empty dependency array, it’ll run exactly once.

If you want to trigger only after setNumberOfPages is triggered for the first time then the way you're using it is right:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (numberOfPages != null) {
      const newArr = splitArray(issues, numberOfPages);
      console.log('new arr');
      console.log(newArr);
    }
  }, [numberOfPages]);
```

Additionally, you can check out this awesome StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59841947/16420018

And this article by Dan Abramov:
https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Answer (score 1):

the useEffect you have (2nd) would be run on the initial render, and then every subsequent render where numberOfPages changes its value.

*Problem is that, the second useEffect, is triggered on load, when numberOfPages is null, shouldn't it be triggered only after setNumberOfPages is triggered for the first time?*

you cannot escape the initial render. but conditionally you can make it do nothing as you did. useRef is also used to escape the effect of initial render.