# useState is executed even dependency doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have to fetch an API when a state changes, i've used useEffect adding the dependency like this

```
const [ activeLottery, setActiveLottery ] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('fetching')
}, [activeLottery])
return (
    <div className="container">
        <Carousel 
            lotteries={ lotteries } 
            isLoading={ isLoading }
            slideClick={ setActiveLottery }
        />
    </div>
);
```

The Component Carousel has an onClick function which changes activeLottery and it works properly since the state is mutated. But it executes the fetch when the component is rendered. Shouldn't do it when activeLottery changes?

Any hint would be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: useEffect runs first when the component is rendered and then every time anything from the dependency array changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make React useEffect hook not run on initial render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render)

Comment: yes! finally i've added a conditional checking activeLottery, same as answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, **`useEffect` always runs after the first render.**

The dependency array in useEffect lets you specify the conditions to trigger it. If you provide useEffect an empty dependency array, it’ll run exactly once.

If you want to make API call when `activeLottery` changes then write condition inside `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(activeLottery?.length){ // if activeLottery is array then you can check it's length
    // Your API call goes here
    }
    console.log('fetching')
}, [activeLottery])
```

Additionally, you can check out this awesome StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59841947/16420018

And this article by Dan Abramov: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: Awesome! finally i've added the conditional just checking if activeLottery was yet filled. Many thanks!