# How to re-initialize default value of useState() in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, timer

## Background

I'm making timer using React-Hook and Functional Component.
The code below is working well.

```
type TProps = {
  startTime: string;
  lapTime: number;
};

export default function RemainTime({ lapTime }: TProps) {
  const [lt, setLapTime] = useState<number>(lapTime);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('lapTime is changed');
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('setInterval is called');
      setLapTime((prev) => prev - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      console.log('component unmounted');
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [lapTime]);
  return <div>Remain Time : {lt}</div>;
}
```

The `lt` changes every second.

## Problem

Even though I re-render the `RemainTime` component with new props(`{ lapTime: 300 }`), the `lt` has a previous value.

## What I want

I want the `RemainTime` component to render new time when the `lapTime` is changed.

Comment: You have a useEffect for lapTime change, you only need to set it, setLapTime(lapTime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer.

```
type TProps = {
  startTime: string;
  lapTime: number;
};

export default function RemainTime({ lapTime: initialLapTime }: TProps) {
  const [lapTime, setLapTime] = useState<number>(initialLapTime);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLapTime(initialLapTime);
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setLapTime((prev) => prev - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      console.log('component unmounted');
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [initialLapTime]);
  return <div>Remain Time : {lapTime}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Every useEffect should have a single responsibility, you should move this logic to another useEffect. Check it in React docs or/and notes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947