# TypeScript error for react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to TypeScript & React so bear with me, but getting:

```
Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'action'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'action' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

for:

```
function useHandleOutsideClick(ref, action: () => void) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClickOutside(event) {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        action();
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref]);
}
```

Not sure if it matters, but this sits outside of the actual component export.

Doing some reading on `useCallback` & I attempted to move `handleClickOutside` outside of `useHandleOutsideClick`, but then got a missing parameter for event:

```
const handleClickOutside = useCallback(
  (event, ref, action) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
      action();
    }
  },
  [ref]
);

function useHandleOutsideClick(ref, action: () => void) {
  useEffect(() => {
    handleClickOutside(event, ref, action);

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref]);
}
```

But then got missing `ref`. Feels like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Its not typescript problem, its a linter warning, and it suggests to add `action` function to the dep array (there are plenty similar questions + react docs). `useEffect(() => {...}, [ref, action]`. So basically your question is how to fix the warning?

Comment: Moreover adding ref in dep array is an anti pattern (ref.current change does not trigger rerender) you can get more context here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `action` to the list of dependencies if you want to use this inside `useEffect`.

For example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  /* ... */
}, [ref, action]); // dependencies
```